# Problema em divisao e multiplicação

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um exercício pra fazer as quatro operações básicas, mas multiplicação/divisão não está indo, e tem que testar se o numero q está dividindo não é zero. Porem soma e subtração ta certo.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Primeiro Projeto</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function calcSoma(){
                var a=$("#num1").val(); 
                var b=$("#num2").val();
                var c= parseInt(a)+parseInt(b);
                $("#num3").val(c);
            }
            function calcSub(){
                var a=$("#num1").val(); 
                var b=$("#num2").val();
                var c= parseInt(a)-parseInt(b);

                $("#num3").val(c);
            }
            function calcDiv(){
                var a=$("num1").val();
                var b=$("num2").val();
                if(b != "0"){
                    var c= parseInt(a)/parseInt(b);
                    $("#num3").val(c);
                }else{
                    $("#num3").val("Dividendo é 0");                    
                }
            }
            function calcMult(){
                var a=$("num1").val();
                var b=$("num2").val();
                var c= parseFloat(a)*parseFloat(b);

                $("#num3").val(c);
            }

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        Número1: <input type="text" size="2px" id="num1"><br>
        Número2: <input type="text" size="2px" id="num2"><br>       
        <button onclick="calcSoma()">+</button>
        <button onclick="calcSub()">-</button>
        <button onclick="calcDiv()">/</button>
        <button onclick="calcMult()">*</button><br>
        Resultado:<input type="text" size="2px" id="num3">


    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples, você esqueceu o **octothorpe** ou cerquilha no `id` tanto na divisão quanto na multiplicação:

Você colocou:

`var a=$("num1").val();`

Deveria ser:

`var a=$("#num1").val();`

**DICA**

```
function calcMult() {
    var a = $("num1").val(),
        b = $("num2").val(),
        c = parseFloat(a) * parseFloat(b);

    $("#num3").val(c);
}
```

Você pode usar `var` somente uma vez para várias variáveis declaradas e sequência, desde que você separe cada uma por vírgula. É uma sintaxe que eu gosto. Mantém tudo mais simples, desde que bem indentado.

Comment: Nao acredito que tava quebrando a cabeça por isso :/. Obrigado!

Comment: Se te ajudou, dá um *upvote*. Se resolveu seu problema, marque como resposta.

Comment: Nao sabia dessa regra da sintaxe, ajuda bem, e deixa mais limpo o código. Só identar direitinho. Vlw

Comment: Boa sorte! Se puder estudo o livro do Jon Ducket sobre JavaScript. Vale a pena!

Answer (score 1):

troque:

```
var a=$("num1").val();
var b=$("num2").val();
```

para:

```
var a=$("#num1").val();
var b=$("#num2").val();
```

`'#'` é selector para elemento através do atributo id

Answer (score 0):

Em uma das minhas necessidades parecida com a sua, cheguei a essa conclusão:

```
var sum = $('.larg').text(); 
var sum2 = $('.alt').text();
var sum3 = $('.metro').text();

if(sum == "") sum = 0;
if(sum2 == "") sum2 = 0;
if(sum3 == "") sum3 = 0;

var resultado = parseInt(sum) * parseInt(sum2) * parseInt(sum3);
```